# SQLAlchemy Table Definition to Python Code

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if there's any utility for printing out a SQLAlchemy Table definition as python code (both Core and ORM style would be even better).  I've found that the [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html) capability is really nice for doing quick prototyping, but I'm considering using declarative Table objects for long-term use.  Since I'm currently loading the tables using reflection, it would be great if I could just `to_python()` and get the python code definition of the object that I could copy and paste into a python file.

I tried using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) to print a Table object and it seems pretty close to what I want for Core, but it includes some syntax that doesn't translate directly to python.

```
Table('MY_TABLE',
    MetaData(),
    Column('doc_id', NUMBER(precision=10, scale=0, asdecimal=False), table=<MY_TABLE>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x000002464EE0CE80>, for_update=False)),
    Column('function_code', VARCHAR(length=30), table=<MY_TABLE>, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('text_data', CLOB(), table=<MY_TABLE>, nullable=False),
    Column('attch_cnt', NUMBER(precision=5, scale=0, asdecimal=False), table=<MY_TABLE>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x000002464EE0CEB0>, for_update=False)),
    Column('attch_type', NUMBER(precision=5, scale=0, asdecimal=False), table=<MY_TABLE>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x000002464EE992E0>, for_update=False)),
    Column('blob_id', NUMBER(precision=10, scale=0, asdecimal=False), table=<MY_TABLE>),
    schema=None)
```

Worst comes to worst, I can just take the `repr()` output and massage it as needed, but I'm hoping I can find something to eliminate a lot of the tedious editing for large tables.

Comment: Have you seen https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen ? I find the output needs to be shaped a little bit after it's done, but it was a great starting point for one of my projects working with an existing database.

Comment: @flakes That website only lists support for SQLAlchemy up to version 1.3.  However, I see on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) it lists support for 1.4 (which is what I'm using).  I'll have to check it out.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Upon further inspection, the v1.4 support appears to be part of the beta version, not the latest release.  The latest release (2.3.0 at the time of writing) still only supports SQLAlchemy v1.3.  Hopefully they'll be able to get v1.4 support eventually!